# Automatically collapsing sidebar of R Bookdown website

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

It is critical that people reading my Bookdown project do not skip chapters. While it is explicitly stated in the document, further discouraging this by automatically collapsing the sidebar would be really helpful :o)

According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/130) there is no default explicit option to do this, but is there any other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

Using e.g. the [inspect feature](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles) of Chrome on a bookdown::gitbook you see that the first element in the DOM after `<body>` is a `<div>` which 'contains' the whole book. This `<div>` has multiple classes, one of them is `with-summary` and this is the one you'd like to remove.

I think the quickest way to do this is jusing jquery:

1. Set up an HTML file

   **header.html**

   ```html
   <script>
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
     $("div").first().removeClass("with-summary");
    });
   </script>
   ```
2. Include the file in the document header using the YAML option `includes` in your

   **.Rmd**

   ```yaml
   ---
   title: "My Title"
   output: 
     bookdown::gitbook:
       includes:
         in_header: header.html
   ---
   ```

After the page load, the jquery function will pick the first `<div>` element in the DOM and remove the class. Note that this will hide the sidebar if the user navigates to another chapter, too.

Comment: What a warm welcome! Thank you very much for your help, you're an absolute champion.